# Facebook all.js and Google googleapis.client__plusone.js downloads twice

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

[My website](http://bit.ly/eeyWyS) it shows `all.js` and `__plusone.js` as downloading twice in both Chrome and Firefox's web developer consoles. As far as I can tell, they aren't included in the page twice anywhere, so I'm not really sure what's going on.

I use the `<fb:like` and `<g:plus` markup, so it's not being downloaded through an iframe. Facebook is loaded asynchronously with `window.fbasync = function() { load the js..}` at the very bottom of the `min.js` script on that page. G+ just has the one JS file at the bottom of the page.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an iframe is being created within the page when you add G+ and like. Looks like those iframes are referring to the files.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Seems weird that Google would load the same thing twice inside its iframe though. I think the plusone.js that you include calls __plusone.js, and the iframe then calls it again. As for facebook all.js, it seems that somehow fixed itself. I noticed one method though - adding a channelUrl fixed it from calling twice in IE.